# ImportError: No module named scipy.spatial after conda install

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, conda

I have installed the module called scipy, and want to use it in my program.

This is the full list of my conda installation:

```
(env_dlib) $ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/sineka/anaconda3/envs/env_dlib:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
blas                      1.0                    openblas  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2019.11.28           hecc5488_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
certifi                   2019.11.28               py36_0    conda-forge
click                     7.0                      py36_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.6               he372182_0    conda-forge
dlib                      19.19            py36h5245418_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
ffmpeg                    4.0                  hcdf2ecd_0  
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freeglut                  3.0.0                hf484d3e_5  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1  
glib                      2.63.1               h5a9c865_0  
graphite2                 1.3.13               h23475e2_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.5               h0935bb2_0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.14.5               h36ae1b5_0    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hffaf4a1_0  
hdf5                      1.10.2               hba1933b_1  
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
imutils                   0.5.3                    py36_0    conda-forge
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py36_0  
jasper                    2.0.14               h07fcdf6_1  
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0  
jpeg                      9c                h14c3975_1001    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py36hc9558a2_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libblas                   3.8.0               14_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0               14_openblas    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libglu                    9.0.0                hf484d3e_1  
liblapack                 3.8.0               14_openblas    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.7                h5ec1e0e_6    conda-forge
libopencv                 3.4.2                hb342d67_1  
libopus                   1.3                  h7b6447c_0  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_0  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libvpx                    1.7.0                h439df22_0  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hea5a465_1  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py36h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.1.1            py36h5429711_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
numpy                     1.17.5           py36h95a1406_0    conda-forge
opencv                    3.4.2            py36h6fd60c2_1  
openssl                   1.1.1d               h516909a_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.43                 he6710b0_0  
pip                       19.3.1                   py36_0  
pixman                    0.38.0               h7b6447c_0  
py-opencv                 3.4.2            py36hb342d67_1  
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36hcca6a23_4    conda-forge
python                    3.6.10               h0371630_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
scipy                     1.3.2            py36he2b7bc3_0  
setuptools                44.0.0                   py36_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py36hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.14.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.30.1               h7b6447c_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
tornado                   6.0.3            py36h516909a_0    conda-forge
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.6                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

As you can see, I have installed the scipy module from conda and I got no error when importing it into PyCharm. But, when I run the program, I got the error "no module named scipy.spatial".

This is how I import the module:

[image: import module]

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you show how you are importing it?

Comment: i'll try to update it in the post

Comment: @ScottM there i've added the picture. That should work right?

Comment: How are you executing the code? Are you within the proper conda env? Thanks for the picture btw

Comment: @ScottM the way i execute the code is by doing this:
python camera_web2.py -p MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt -m MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel.

Yes, i'm in the proper conda env

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error. The only difference I see is that I have scipy version 1.3.1

Comment: hmm... i'll try version 1.3.1 then. if it still not working, idk.

Comment: @ScottM nope, doesn't work with 1.3.1 either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206488/discussion-between-rheza001-and-scott-m).